# Which model is the best for training oriented bounding boxes for small objects

Tags: training-data, yolov5

I have a dataset of some small fibrous objects on which I tried with YOLOv5OBB method but the results are not satisfying.
The detection result is poor (P=0.3, R=0.28 for total boxes = 1200 in 120 images).
The boxes are not fit well to the objects and often there are overlapped boxes in different orientation.
The considered fibrous objects include fibrous with less than 3 microns in diameters and longer than 5 microns, therefore I can not use scaling and shearing which change the size of the objects. traslate and mosaic will also damage the results as objects are cut.
Do you have any suggestion how to improve it? hyp parameters or even a different method/model?
Some output examples:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCJvo.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaLNo.jpg)

**Hyp parameters:**

lr0: 0.00258
lrf: 0.017
momentum: 0.779
weight_decay: 0.00058
warmup_epochs: 1.93
warmup_momentum: 0.443
warmup_bias_lr: 0.059
box: 0.0339
cls: 0.33
cls_pw: 0.825
theta: 0.299
theta_pw: 0.825
obj: 0.632
obj_pw: 1.0
iou_t: 0.2
anchor_t: 3.44
anchors: 2.5
fl_gamma: 0.0
hsv_h: 0.0188
hsv_s: 0.354
hsv_v: 0.35
degrees: 0.03
translate: 0.05
scale: 0.02
shear: 0.0
perspective: 0.0
flipud: 0.7
fliplr: 0.7
mosaic: 0.0
mixup: 0.5
copy_paste: 0.4
cls_theta: 180
csl_radius: 2.0

Comment: Hi!  

For this to reach the right audience who can help, it would be useful to include what language this is written in as a tag, along with some well formatted code to produce a minimal reproducible example - along with your output.  

Try editing your question and adding that information to get better help from the community!

Comment: --epochs 500 --batch-size 16 --img 640 --single-cls --cfg ./models/yolov5x.yaml